# Reasons for not working of Intent android studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new to android programming. I am facing problem in opening another activity on the button click. Also, I am attaching the code which I have written.

This is my **MainActivity** class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    TextView ed1;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my **LoginScreen** class is as follows:

```
public class LoginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;
    EditText ed1,ed2;
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name= ed1.getText().toString();
                String pass=ed2.getText().toString();
                if(name.equals(" ")|| pass.equals(" ")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Required Field",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After running this code, only the first class i.e `MainActivity` runs and after that device displays that the program has stopped working.

Comment: **WILD GUESS** (you didn't post your logcat): You get a `NullPointerException`. I can already see where it does happen.

Comment: Please edit your question. It is not clear what are you asking. Try to minimize you code, and write the exception you are getting (if any).

Comment: Also, do not forget to add the class definition which is : android.content.Intent;

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your `LoginScreen` class. You forgot to initialize `btn1` before setting `OnClickListener`.

```
public class LoginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;
    EditText ed1,ed2;
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name= ed1.getText().toString();
                String pass=ed2.getText().toString();
                if(name.equals(" ")|| pass.equals(" ")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Required Field",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }    
}
```